# Route issue with MVC3 with multiple controller names

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

here is my navigation hierarchy.

- Catalog 
    -Collection 
   - Media 
   - Attributes 
   - User
- Collection 
    -Media 
   - Products 
   - Attributes

I have controller for all. This is what my url should look like

```
http://Localhost/Catalog/Collection/1  // return all collection for catalogeid 1
http://Localhost/Catalog/Media/1  // return all media for catalogeid 1
http://Localhost/Collection/Media/1  // return all media for collectionid 1
```

Now with default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

It looks for  action”Collection” in my “Catalog” Controller ,as I have already define “List” method in “Collection” Controller, I don’t want to redefine same in my “Collection”
Then I tried this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Catalog_Collection_List", // Route name
            "Catalog/Collection/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Collection", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

But result is the same.
Another problem is how to generating link as I mentioned above.
I cant use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Collection","Collection", "List", new { id = 1 })
```

As this generates link like

```
Localhost/Collection/List/1   //I don’t want
```

My ultimate goal is that all the action related to “Collection” should go under “Collection” controller.
i dont know what i am missing.
hope my question is clear.
thanks for any help.
****EDIT****
making my question more clear. take a look this sample url

```
localhost/Catalog/Media/1    // which gives media for catalog
localhost/Collection/Media/1 // which gives media for collection.
```

now as per conventional way i have to define "Media" action in each controller. which i dont want. what i want is based on URL i want to invoke "List" action from "Media" controller.
i hope this is pretty clear.

Comment: have you tried to change the ordering of your routes? It matters

Comment: thx @Emmanuel. i dint get the point.which order i have to change?

Comment: The order your routes are being added on global.asax, [check out this](http://www.freddes.se/2009/12/09/the-importance-of-the-order-of-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im having a bit of a hard time following the problem here. You dont want the url above /collection/list but that is what you specified in your action link. Looking at your URLs you have a consistency problem to start.

"It looks for action”Collection” in my “Catalog” table ,as I have already define method “List” method in “Collection” table, I don’t want to redefine same in my “Collection” Then I tried this" by table I think you mean controller here right?

So you should stick to the format in general Url = /Controller/Action/id
Collection/List/1.

You can absolutely map it somewhere else (and the order is surely important - the first match in your routing table wins)- but ask yourself if you want to deviate from the standard so far.

**EDIT**
I believe you want this route, add it BEFORE your other routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Catalog_Collection_List", // Route name
            "Catalog/Media/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Collection", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: thanks @Adam. i have edited my question. let me know if it does not make more sense.

Comment: the reason why i am doing this is to avoid confusion whether user is looking at Collection media or Catalog media.